# javascript not able to sort complex array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following array to sort.

```
const input = ["12 - Blue, Red, Orange, Purple", 
"16 - White, Black, Yellow, Blue, Pink",
"14 -  Yellow, Brown, Grey, Maroon, Green",
"20 - Red, Black, Yellow, Peach, Aqua",
"7 - White, Cream, Grey, Green, Magenta" ]
```

The aim is to sort rows in ascending order like 7th row, then 12th, 14th, 16th finally 20th. Here is what I tried but not working

```js
const input = [
  "12 - Blue, Red, Orange, Purple",
  "16 - White, Black, Yellow, Blue, Pink",
  "14 -  Yellow, Brown, Grey, Maroon, Green",
  "20 - Red, Black, Yellow, Peach, Aqua",
  "7 - White, Cream, Grey, Green, Magenta"
]

var x = input.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a[0] > b[0] ? 1 : -1;
});

console.log(x)
```

How to sort such a complex array in ascending order?

Comment: `input.sort((a,b)=>{ return parseInt((a.split('-')[0]).trim()) - parseInt((b.split('-')[0]).trim()) })` - assuming your format(<integer> - <string>) will not change.

Comment: this does not look complex in my opinion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to take the integer values and sort by the delta of it.

```js
const
    input = ["12 - Blue, Red, Orange, Purple",
        "16 - White, Black, Yellow, Blue, Pink",
        "14 -  Yellow, Brown, Grey, Maroon, Green",
        "20 - Red, Black, Yellow, Peach, Aqua",
        "7 - White, Cream, Grey, Green, Magenta"
    ];

input.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseInt(a, 10) - parseInt(b, 10);
});

console.log(input);
```

With sorted colors.

```js
const
    input = ["12 - Blue, Red, Orange, Purple",
        "16 - White, Black, Yellow, Blue, Pink",
        "14 -  Yellow, Brown, Grey, Maroon, Green",
        "20 - Red, Black, Yellow, Peach, Aqua",
        "7 - White, Cream, Grey, Green, Magenta"
    ],
    sorted = input
        .map(s => {
            const [number, colors] = s.split(' - ');
            return [
                number,
                colors
                    .split(/,\s*/)
                    .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))
                    .join(', ')
            ].join(' - ');
        })
       .sort((a, b) => parseInt(a, 10) - parseInt(b, 10));

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: is the `10` required? i tried it without and it works aswell

Comment: Thank you. How to sort color names alphabetically after sorting of numbers?

Comment: in this case, you need to iterate again and separate the items and sort the items.

Comment: Sorry, but can you add to your code? Please